# Query for file group of Service Broker Queue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

How do you query the file group of a Service Broker Queue object in SQL Server?

I can see the information via SQL Server Management Studio, by looking at the Properties of the Queue, but I'd like to be able to query for the information in a script.

It doesn't seem I can use the same methods as for querying the filegroup of a table - but maybe I've missed something?

Comment: Check out the system tables described here, might find something useful... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173780.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to look for the internal table with `parent_object_id` matching the queue:

```
select o.* 
from sys.service_queues q
join sys.objects o on o.parent_object_id = q.object_id;
```

Comment: Thanks - this led me (via http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/06/01/sql-server-list-all-objects-created-on-all-filegroups-in-database/) to 
`select q.name, f.name
from sys.service_queues q
join sys.objects o on o.parent_object_id = q.object_id
join sys.indexes i on i.object_id = o.object_id
join sys.filegroups f on f.data_space_id = i.data_space_id`